# How to use boost::multi_index composite keys

Tags: c++, boost

My requirement need a map like this:

```
pair<string key1, string key2> _keypair;
map<_keypair, shared_ptr<classX>>
```

My needs are:

1. key1 and key2 pair has to be unique.
2. I should be able to access using key1 and Key2 pair.
3. Insert.
4. Delete using composite keys

I came across `boost::multi_index` but am not that clear with it. Can someone give me an example for my situation?

Answer (score 1):

smth like this (I didn't compile this code):

```
struct value_type
{
    std::string key1_;
    std::string key2_;
    std::shared_ptr<some_class> ptr_;
};

// index tags (otherwise you have to use number when get<N>() corresponding index)
struct composite_index;
struct key1_index;
struct key2_index;

using namespace boost::multi_index;
typedef multi_index_container<
    value_type
  , indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<
            tag<composite_index>
          , composite_key<
                value_type
              , member<value_type, std::string, &value_type::key1_>
              , member<value_type, std::string, &value_type::key2_>
              >
          >
      , ordered_non_unique<
            tag<key1_index>
          , member<value_type, std::string, &value_type::key1_>
          >
      >
      , ordered_non_unique<
            tag<key2_index>
          , member<value_type, std::string, &value_type::key2_>
          >
      >
  > index_type;

index_type a;
a.insert({"key-1", "key-2", std::shared_ptr<some_class>(new some_class(...)});

// find by key1_index (or key2_index)
auto range = a.get<key1_index>().equal_range("key-1");

// find by composite index
auto it = a.get<composite_index>().find(std::make_tuple("key-1", "key-2"));

// erase by any iterator type
a.erase(it);
```

Comment: thanks zaufi it works pretty well except i had to use boost::make_tuple instead of std::make_tuple.but i have a problem while erasing it shows error "  No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called" any idea ?